# IDTWizard : Verification of Project and Solution Name

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating an IDTWizard for the New Project Window in Visual Studio. I need the user to enter the Project/Solution Name in a specific format i.e. "A.B.C.D". The problem is that the only way I can access the New Project Window is by the Execute() method in the IDTWizard interface. New Project Window closes and opens the custom form and I am not able to perform the check in the New Project Window itself.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control what the user types in the New Project Window, but in the Execute() method you can check the name the user entered. When the name is wrong, you can show an error message and set

```
retval = wizardResult.wizardResultBackOut;
```

This will return the user to the New Project Window, where he can correct the name.